# How do you change the background of a QTableWidget heading

Tags: qtablewidget, qt6

I am able to change the foreground color, but not the background color.

I have tried:

```
    for col in range(self.table.columnCount()):
        item = self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(col)
        item.setForeground(foreground) # foreground changes as expected
        item.setBackground(foreground) # does not affect the background color
```

and:

```
    self.table.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet("color: red; background-color: blue")
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated